# Ошибка компиляции в java

Tags: java

[image: Ошибка]

Делаю все по книге, код:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);

        DetailFragment frag = (DetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
        frag.setWorkout(1);
    }
}
```

DetailFragment: (это другой файл-класс)

```
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private long workoutId;

    public WorkoutDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
    }
    public void setWorkout(long id){
        this.workoutId = id;
    }
}
```

На -

```
WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
```

> Текст - **Error:(16, 84)** error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to WorkoutDetailFragment

Comment: что за ошибка? на что ругается? какой текст ошибки?

Comment: На - WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
Текст - Error:(16, 84) error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to WorkoutDetailFragment

Comment: добавь это все в сам вопрос, сам текст

Comment: Готово
ps не успел прочитать ответ

Comment: Проверь полное имя класса от которого наследуешься

Comment: Да я потом увидел - он тут не совсем подходит, проблема аналогичная но классы другие

Comment: @Grundy, а почему ответ удалили?.. Вроде бы он верный же...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, он верен для того вопрос с которого я перевел, тут на сколько я понимаю от другого класса надо наследоваться, а не того который в ответе

Comment: Все как по книге - public class DetailFragment extends Fragment; вызов DetailFragment frag = (DetailFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
Дайте тот ответ, попробую

Comment: Восстановил, но смотрите - полное имя класса от которого наследуетесь и полное имя класс к которому пытаетесь привести. Они могу отличаться из-за используемых импортов если использовать короткие названия

Comment: Вообщем решил проблему исходя из ответа, нужно было не "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" импортировать (что делает андроид студио), а android.app.Fragment

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев, ответ вообще говоря обратное советует :-D

Comment: @Grundy, да, но благодаря ему я посмотрел на импорт и нашел ошибку.
ps репнул все равно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как подсказывают в ответе на [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386320/incompatible-types-fragment-cannot-be-converted-to-navigationdrawerfragment)

Ваш фрагмент должен наследоваться от `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (возможно более актуальную версию), а не обычный `Fragment` класс.

Comment: Я его как раз импортирую (точнее студия уже добавила его)

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев, в каком месте? в обоих файлах? нужно проверить что `extends` и приведение потом для одинаковых классов идет

Comment: Я просто невнимательно смотрел на импорт в книге. В DetailFragment надо импортировать android.app.Fragment, a не android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 2):

Андроид студио импортирует android.support.v4.app.Fragment
А нужно - android.app.Fragment;